# What is the REAL webpack.js version in my --webpacker=react Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

Ruby 2.7.1, yarn 1.22.5, Rails 6.0.4.4, node v16.13.1

I have followed this tutorial at
https://stevepolito.design/blog/rails-react-tutorial/

It would automatically install webpacker 4.3.0 in my Gemfile.lock

However, I got a "Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError" before "Load Bootstrap" section of the tutorial.

Thanks to mehmoodak at https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1730, I have fixed the error by "yarn add @rails/webpacker"

Finally, I am checking what version of webpack.js is

yarn list webpack, shows webpack@4.46.0

Gemfile.lock, shows webpacker (4.3.0)

package.json, shows "@rails/webpacker": "^5.4.3"

I am very confused of what version of my webpack.js is in my rails applications?

Are "webpack", "webpacker", or "@rails/webpacker" different in some ways?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Webpacker is a ruby gem, https://rubygems.org/gems/webpacker that works in the asset pipeline.

Webpack is webpack